# which memory upgrade is best?

Tags: ram

Running Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on a machine with ASUS M2N-e board,
I sometimes receive buffer lockups when watching YouTube.
I have (two) 1 GB sticks of PC2-5300 667 MHz of DDR2 RAM (Kingston) installed.

Would it be better performance to install two more identical memory sticks in the two open slots or remove what I have and put in two 2 GB sticks of a higher speed rating?

Thanks,

Comment: Err... I think you ain't asking in the better place, but the bigger the memory is, normally is the better. Of course with DDR2 you have to put both sticks in the same channel to make use of the maximunn bandwidth.

Comment: define "buffer lockups".  If you mean the video stops and it says it is buffering, that is because your connection is slow and has nothing to do with ram.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare cases where quantity is better than quality. I doubt you could notice a difference between PC2-5300 vs PC2-6400 in daily usage. If you are on a budget choose the solution that costs you less, the biggest difference comes from the amount of RAM.

That being said, having 2x2GB gives you room for future expansions while with 4x1GB you probably end up with all the slots taken. So a wise choice might be to take bigger/faster memory sticks. Of course check if the new memory is compatible with your CPU/motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

PC2-6400 is the bare minimum.You need to change to 800MHz or higher frequency RAM if your
motherboard supports it.Indeed quantity is crucial too but replacing the 2*1GB sitcks with 2*1GB 800MHz sticks with better CAS latency would make quite a difference.